# if ${x_n}$ is monotone increasing and bounded, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n$ = sup${x_n:n\in N}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Prove if ${x_n}$ is monotone increasing and bounded, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n$ = sup${x_n:n\in N}$.

Suppose there exists a $B$ such that $x_n\le B$ for all $n$, and let $x$ = sup${x_n: n\in N}$.

Let $\varepsilon \gt 0$ be arbitrary.

**As $x$ is the supremum, then there must be at least one $M \in N$ such that $x_M \ge x-\varepsilon$ (because $x$ is the supremum) .**

As ${x_n}$ is monotone increasing, then it is easy to see (by induction) that $x_n \ge x_M$ for all $n \ge M$.

Hence, 
$|x_n-x|=x-x_n\le x-x_M\lt \varepsilon$.

I don't understnad one part of this proof. If $x$ is larger than B, and $\varepsilon$ is really small, $x-\varepsilon$ might be still larger than B, but how do we know that there must be at least one $M$ such that $x_M \ge x-\varepsilon$ ??

Comment: First, $x$ cannot be larger than $B$, as $x$ is the least upper  bound and $B$ is an upper bound.  In fact $B$ does not play any role in the proof at all.  Start with "since the sequence $(x_n)$ is bounded above, it has a least upper bound $x$.

Comment: The reason for the existence of $M$l is that $x$ is the least upper bound and therefore, for any $\epsilon > 0$, $x - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound.

Comment: Um.. let's say $x_1=1, x_2=2, ...... , x_5=5$ and B is 5.5, so $x=6$. If $\varepsilon = 0.5$ then $x-\varepsilon = 5.5$. Then, it is still larger than $x_5$, which means $M$ does not exist. Could you tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Ah, so do you mean in this case, $x_5$ must be $x$, so $M=5$ ?